# Mark as Duplicate after answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492445/conversion-of-strings-to-datetime-pandas-tried-everything#46492519) which seems like a duplicate that is asked pretty frequently. I would normally tag it as a duplicate to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133018/convert-pandas-series-to-datetime-in-a-dataframe).

However, because the OP did not post the output of using that answer - I am hesitant to mark it as a duplicate because his/her scenario *may* be different.

at the time of my writing An answer was posted that I believe would solve the OP's problem. If that is the case - it *is* a duplicate.

The bottom line regardless of this scenario: should you mark a question as a duplicate *after* an accepted answer - if the answer is the same as other posts?

Comment: it it's unclear... it's unclear. If it's missing information, it's missing information.

Comment: @KevinB. That was another thought... but it's only unclear in one section of not showing an output - the rest of the question is pretty decent

Comment: @MattR Either the question contains enough information to be answered, and it's not unclear, or it doesn't contain enough information to be answered, and it's unclear.  It doesn't matter how many aspects of the question are well written; if it lack sufficient information to be answered, it merits closure for that reason (until that issue is corrected).

Comment: Though... i usually leave a comment asking for the additional information before casting that vote so that i can dupe hammer it once it's added rather than wasting my vote on a reason that won't matter once an edit is made. Not longer than a few minutes.

Comment: @KevinB, I did the same. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you believe that the answer to the question asked is answered by the duplicate, then vote to close as a duplicate.  If the OP's problem has difference that they didn't include in their question that make the duplicate not applicable, they can edit their question to distinguish it from the duplicate.

The existence of an answer shouldn't have any bearing on your decision here.

Comment: It ended up being a duplicate. The answer was the same/Very similar to the other question. If this was not a duplicate - what should this be flagged for? in my opinion (which could be wrong): It is not "Very low quality" - it is salvagable. It is not "too broad", it is not "
unclear of what you're asking"

Comment: @MattR If you feel that a posts merits flagging for a particular reason, then flag it for that reason.  If you don't think a post merits flagging for any reason then...don't flag it for any reason.

Comment: If you flag it as a duplicate and it gets closed as a duplicate and it's not a duplicate....its not your problem, it's the asker's to refine their question and show that it is not a duplicate.